# Rails - Know caller filename when using render layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout

I want to dynamically add classes to a container based on the name of the class that called my layout using the `render` method. Is it possible or do I need to pass it manually from each view?

File: **emails/inbox.html.haml**

```
render layout: 'shared/v3/panel' do
  // whatever
```

Rendered HTML:

```
<div id="inbox" class="panel email_container"></div>
```

My temp solution is to do:

```
render layout: 'shared/v3/panel', locals: {class_panel: 'email_container', id_panel: 'inbox'} do
  // whatever
```

But I want to do that dynamically.

---

**Final solution: views/shared/_panel.html.haml**

```
- # You need to use: "render layout", not "render partial" to pass the "do" block.
.container_content{class: "#{controller_name}_container #{local_assigns[:panel_class] ? panel_class : ''}", id: action_name}
  - if local_assigns[:title]
    .headline= local_assigns[:title]
  = yield

  - if local_assigns[:footer]
    .footer= local_assigns[:footer]

- # Example of use:
-#= render layout: 'shared/v3/panel', locals: {title: 'Place', panel_class: 'my_custom_class'} do
-#  - if @activity.place.present?
-#    %p
-#      = t('place')
-#      = @activity.place
```

Comment: I'm going to try using action_name and controller_name, could be exactly what I want!

Comment: `action_name` and `controller_name` was perfect for this purpose, didn't think about it, I was focused on the filename.